# Cannot access MySQL using command prompt in Windows10

Tags: mysql

i am trying to use MySQL along with php and am aware of the fact that MySQL comes in as a part of the wamp package. however, i am not able to run MySQL through command prompt. i tried looking up a few videos for the same on youtube and happened to notice that all the users had a "MySQL" folder in their `C:\user\programfiles` directory.

I do not have that folder. so now, do I have to install MySQL separately or is there an alternative?

Comment: Wherever MySQL is installed needs to be present in you `%PATH%` environment variable, or else cmd will not be able to locate it. See https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: So, you have MySQL installed?  Or you don't?  If it's installed, you'll need to find its folder and run the command from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql bin folder should be (by default) at
`C:\WAMP\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.XX\bin`

If you add that directory to your path, (changing XX for the actual number on the folder), you should be able to run mysql commands from command prompt